# Unable to update the database at vTiger server

Tags: php, mysql, crm, vtiger

I'am developping an android application for vTiger CRM, and when i create a new contact record from my android app it's correctly added to the vtiger database (crmentity, contactdetails, contactaddress, contactsubdetails and contactscf) tables and i'am able to find the same record in my android app. but it don't display on Vtiger web application (this new record don't display in the listview of Vtiger web application when i refresh the page).
i couldn't figure out the problem, i think there's something wrong with my web service.

help much appreciated.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vtiger_crmentity (crmid,smcreatorid,smownerid,modifiedby,setype,createdtime,modifiedtime,version,deleted) 
values('37','1','1','1','1','2014-04-21 12:32:01','2014-04-21 12:32:01','1','1')") or die(mysql_error());

$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vtiger_contactdetails(contactid,contact_no,salutation, firstname, lastname, mobile, 
fax,title,department, reportsto, secondaryemail)
VALUES('37','1','$salutation', '$first_name', '$last_name', 
'$mobile_phone', '$fax', '$title', '$department', 
  '$reports_to',  '$secondary_email')") or die(mysql_error());

$result3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vtiger_contactsubdetails(contactsubscriptionid,homephone,otherphone, assistant)
VALUES('37','$homephone','$otherphone', '$assistant')") or die(mysql_error());

$result4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vtiger_contactaddress(contactaddressid,mailingcity,mailingstreet)
VALUES('37','$mailingcity', '$mailingstreet')") or die(mysql_error());


$result5 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vtiger_contactscf(contactid) VALUES('37')") or die(mysql_error());


 $result6 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vtiger_customerdetails(customerid,) VALUES('37')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that you should not manipulate `vtiger_crmentity` directly (either from web app or from external web connection), as the crmentity ID should be managed by vTiger internally.

Also, `vtiger_crmentity` should be completely irrelevant for you as a mobile developer: you either have to work with the WebService API ([official doc here](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservice_reference_manual)) or through the Mobile API, using JSON format.
Since I found no guide for Mobile webservices, I wrote my own: [see here](http://gixworks.github.io/vtiger-mobile-client-ios/)